# Unable to create SystemD user service "Failed to connect to bus: Permission denied"

Tags: server, 20.04, systemd

Trying to run

```
systemctl --user start my-service.service
```

on Ubuntu server 20.04 as a non-root user I get

```
Failed to connect to bus: Permission denied
```

Even just

```
systemctl --user
```

gives the same error.

The user was created with `adduser --disabled-login my-user` and is accessed by running `su my-user`.

[Based on what I found](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/17901) researching this issue it seems that some environment variable is not properly initialised when doing `su` as opposed to "logging in" that causes this.

Show your work:

- `libpam-systemd` as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/934542) is already installed
- Setting `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/895045) did not work

Comment: I'm not really sure how to interpret it, but this seems related [Why isn't a systemd user session started by `su`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703410/why-isnt-a-systemd-user-session-started-by-su)

Comment: Looking back at this, running `su --login` instead of just `su` might've also done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user service is, most likely, not starting because the needed path to the user specific bus socket file at `/run/user/$UID/bus`(*which is part of the user-runtime environment*) is not properly set in the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` ... That should be set to something similar to this:

```
$ echo "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

If not set, then set and export it like so:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus"
```

Then, try starting your user service again.

**Notice**: This, however, requires a user-runtime environment which is set mainly by the service [`user@$UID.service`(*and company*)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/user@.service.5.html)(*`$UID` is the invoking user's ID*) ... Which might as well be a culprit in your situation … If it's not running, start it first with `sudo`(*from an administrator user account*) (**replacing the example `1003` with the actual ID of the user**) like so:

```
sudo systemctl start user@1003.service
```

Comment: I started tracing the end user error which lead me to eventually discussing the user-runtime environment at the end of my answer … Now I think I should have written the answer bottom-up :-) … Make sure you read the **notice** part first.

Comment: Running `sudo systemctl start user@1001.service` and adding `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus"` seems to have done the trick. Thanks! :D