# Error when running docker desktop from cronjob

Tags: cron, docker

I have a script that checks every minute if docker desktop is running.  If it fails, it should launch docker desktop.

My script works fine if I run from command line, but it fails when I run it by cronjob.  Any ideas how to fix this? Ive tried everything.

This is the error:

```
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
com.docker.backend is not running. Starting Docker Desktop...
Error starting Docker Desktop: Command '['systemctl', '--user', 'start', 'docker-desktop']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to run a service that requires a userspace environment without that environment being accessible/present and probably set at that moment … See for example [Unable to create SystemD user service "Failed to connect to bus: Permission denied"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1470010)